# How to convert rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame to csv?

Tags: python, rpy2

After executing my python file i got result as:

```
R object with classes: ('data.frame',) mapped to:
<DataFrame - Python:0x7f3f3c05a388 / R:0x563006a79ea8>
[DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, ..., DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame]
R object with classes: ('data.frame',) mapped to:
<DataFrame - Python:0x7f3f3c05a388 / R:0x563006a79ea8>
[DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, ..., DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame]
R object with classes: ('data.frame',) mapped to:
<DataFrame - Python:0x7f3f3c05a388 / R:0x563006a79ea8>
[DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, ..., DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame]
...
R object with classes: ('data.frame',) mapped to:
<DataFrame - Python:0x7f3f3c05a388 / R:0x563006a79ea8>
[DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, ..., DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame, DataFrame]


len(a)=12
type(a)=rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame
```

I am trying to convert the result dataframe to csv by `a.to_csv('filename.csv')`
But it wont work for the current result. Anybody have any idea about how to convert `'rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame csv'`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing a dataframe to the global environment of R using pandas2ri(you might need to install tzlocal for this) and then pass the whole command as a string where R itself returns the value as a dataframe. Look below for a the reference

```
rdf = pandas2ri.py2ri(self.data)
ro.globalenv['r_timeseries'] = rdf
prediction=ro.r('as.data.frame(stlf(ts(r_timeseries,frequency = 12),h=4,level=c(90)))')
```

To run you through the code: I am first creating a globalenv dataframe named as r_timeseries and passing it below as a string command which you usually would pass in R as well. Here I am using rpy2 to get forecast for 4 periods using STLF.

Go have a try yourself, I hope this would be of some help to you.